# Get a particular file field with the particular data id and clear it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file field like this :

```
<input type='file' class="upload_file" name="gallery_file[]" data-imageid="6"/>
<input type='file' class="upload_file" name="gallery_file[]" data-imageid="7"/>
```

Now i want to access a particular file field that has a specific imageid and empty that file field:

```
var delete_index=jQuery(this).data("imageid");
```

Comment: You mean like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/OJNeRwQ

Comment: do you want to clear by value of imageid?

Comment: @Jerson: Yes I have a delete_index and now i want to clear only particular field with that data-imageid value.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan: Thanks but i don't want to use loop because i have data-imageid and i want to clear it directly

Comment: added answer please look

Comment: i hope my answer works to you, and accept it thanks

Comment: @user3653474, Could you check now? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/OJNeRwQ . You could use ```$(".upload_file[data-imageid='"+deleteImageId+"']").remove()``` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to use [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
const emptyValue = 7

$('.upload_file:not([data-imageid!=' + emptyValue + '])').attr('data-imageid' ,'')
```

or you could remove this element

```
$('.upload_file:not([data-imageid!=' + emptyValue + '])').remove()
```

then you could test here

```
$(".upload_file").each(function(i,obj) {
  console.log($(this).data("imageid"))
})
```